# Christmas eve advice for a backpacker thinking of flying in to Germany

Tags: accommodation, germany, public-holidays

I am currently in Mumbai, India but am thinking of spending the holidays in Germany.

Problem is:

A) I don't know anyone there

B) I am thinking of flying in on christmas eve.

C) I don't know how difficult it would be to find a hostel or room for rent.

I'm not even sure if grocery stores will be open or how limited my food options will be.

Will I end up starving and freezing to death in a ditch or are there places that I can go that would be accomodating to my situation?

Comment: Christmas eve (as per subject) or New Years Eve (as per body)?

Comment: Both days are not official holidays in Germany. So even though, some grocery stores will close earlier than usual, you should still find plenty of food and also hostels.

Comment: Shoot, Christmas eve, not new years eve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Christmas Eve and New Years Eve are both [not official holidays in Germany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Germany). It might be, that a lot of shops close earlier on these days than usual, but generally, you will nevertheless have enough options to buy food. And at last shops at airports, main stations and similar locations are open 365 days a year, so you want have to starve.

Also hostels and hotels are generally available 365 days a year in Germany. However, Christmas Eve is on a short notice and New Years Eve is in great demand, so you should check as soon as possible if there is an accommodation that suites your need.

Comment: I think shops are open more than 36 days a year, even in Germany :-)

Comment: That's true    :)  :)

Comment: Thanks,  I think I've decided not to head to Germany for the moment.